# What's the best way to serve olive oil to a constipated cat?

Tags: cats, health, diet

I've read on the Internet that olive oil is good for constipated cats. I was wondering what's the best way to give it to the cat, as I am afraid of any side effects.

- Is it best with dry or wet food?
- Wouldn't wet food dampen the olive oil's supposed effect as it muddles with it?
- Can anything bad happen to my cat if she eats olive oil with wet or dry food, for example due to some chemicals in the cat food?
- And what's the best way to serve olive oil and keep it's effect at full limit?

She eats Friskies dry and wet food and Whiskas wet food.

Answer (score 4):

First question, are you sure it is constipation? Because urinary problems, colon tumor and many other things cause symptoms similar to that of constipation. Have you checked with vet?

Also note that olive oil is not permanent treatment. It is a short term treatment. If continued cat will develop dependence.

To administer olive oil you need to mix half to one teaspoonful with wet food and give it to cat. It should have effect within a few hours. If not consult a vet. Excessive dose will be toxic.

If vet finds that there are no other underlying health problems then the best course of treatment would be -

1. Giving the cat a high fiber diet.
2. Ensuring that the cat drinks a lot of fresh water.
3. The cat should get enough exercise.

Comment: If you decide to add fibre to the diet, consider pumpkin: https://pets.thenest.com/feeding-canned-pumpkin-cats-dogs-5398.html . You can freeze it in an ice cube tray to preserve it and give one of two cubes (thawed) each day.